# How to find words in a text file?

Tags: python, file, text, word-frequency, alphabetical-sort

I am writing a Python program to which I need to count how many of each word there are in a text file.

```
def count_words(word,d):
    for l in word:
        if l in d:
            d[l] += 1
        else:
            d[l] = 1
        return d

def count_letters():
    d = dict()
    word_file = open('w.txt')
    for line in word_file:
        word = line.strip();
        d = count_words(word,d)
    return d
```

Answer (score 2):

You can easily get away with reverse sorting on one condition and forward sorting on another if one of them is an `int` by negating the `int` in the key func

replace

```
freq_list.sort()
```

with

```
freq_list.sort(key=lambda x:(-x[1], x[0]))
```

In the more general case, since Python's sort is **[stable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Stability)** you can sort by the second key and then the first

```
freq_list.sort(key=lambda x:x[0])
freq_list.sort(key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
```

The disadvantage is that you need to do two sorts, so it's a little slower

Comment: The lambda needs to return a tuple: `(-x[1], x[0])`

Comment: This is exactly why Python 3 made those ambiguous constructs illegal… They're not ambiguous to the interpreter, but there's a 50/50 chance you'll interpret them wrong each time you see them (or write code that looks right but raises mysterious errors like `TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable` when you run them).

Comment: Good answer. For further reading, see the [Sorting HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) in the docs.

Comment: @gnibbler can you take a look at the changes I made to my program and see what I'm doing wrong? It's the same concept, just a completely different look and that's how it is supposed to look.